# Java InputStream Assignment and Non Blocking Reads

Tags: java, inputstream

```java
public class App {

    public static void readSome(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(in.readAllBytes());

        is.read(); // variable number of non blocking reads
        is.read();
        is.read();

        in = is;    // this does nothing
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayInputStream a = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});

        App.readSome(a);
        //something
        App.readSome(a); // should read 4, 5, 6

    }
}
```

Is it possible to change the code in the `readSome` method so that main is able to read all of the values, while readSome completes non blocking reads?

Comment: `InputStream` reads are blocking. There are no non-blocking reads here. Hard to see what magic you are expecting the assignment to perform. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne as per [ByteArrayImputStream docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) `read()` does not block.

Comment: Of course, but the act of consuming the entire stream to fill the `ByteArrayInputStream` leaves nothing to be read subequently by anybody else: and the assignment still does nothing, Java havinga pass-by-value semantics. Hard to see what the actual objective is here. You could just pass the actual byte array around, for example. Probable XY problem.

Comment: Just `public static void readSome(InputStream is) throws IOException { is.read();  is.read(); is.read(); }`, then, the first call will read the values 1, 2, and 3, whereas the next call can read the remaining values 4, 5, 6…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code tries to consume the ByteArrayInputStream two times - this is impossible. And that's it.

```
public class App {
    public static void readSome(InputStream source) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = source.readAllBytes(); // Reads (consumes) all your bytes from the source
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        is.read(); // variable number of non blocking reads
        is.read();
        is.read();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayInputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
        // source full
        App.readSome(source);
        // source fully consumed - so source is empty now
        App.readSome(source); // cannot consume 4, 5, 6 - because source was already consumed.

    }
}
```